# Is it possible to stack transactions?

Tags: transactions, accounts, pending-transactions, txpool, state-transition

Is it possible to stack transactions which depend from themselves?

Example:

State on start: Account A (2 ETH), Account B (0 ETH), Account C (0 ETH)

Transaction 1 - Account A sends 2 ETH to Account B.

Transaction 2 - After few seconds Account B sends 2 ETH to Account C, but the first transactions is not already in block, so Account B has 2 ETH pending and not confirmed.

Question: Will second transaction be rejected by nodes or realized?

Comment: The second transaction won't even reach nodes because trying to broadcast should get an insufficient funds error.  To avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) perhaps try to describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want broadcast some transactions, which results from themselves and don't wait to confirmations. It looks like a stack. 

It's possible in BTC, when you put some transactions to mempool and they can be confirmed in one block.

Comment: As eth says we could probably be more helpful if we knew what @MrSea is trying to achieve. However, the literal question asked is quite interesting. I guess the answer is that in practice the B->C tx will tend to get rejected from mempools, but it would be legal (and also profitable) for a miner to include them both in a block, in the event that they had software clever enough to work out that they should try it.